# select value from drop-down list in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to navigate this drop-down list in BeautifulSoup4 and cannot find a BS4 fuction to insert "selected" in the right place. The list looks like this:

```
 <select name="sport" id="sport" onchange="mask('Processing'); changeSports(this.value);">
  <option value="">Select Sport</option>
    <option value="MBA" >Baseball</option>
    <option value="MBB" >Men&#x27;s Basketball</option>
    <option value="MFB" >Football</option>
    <option value="MIH" >Men&#x27;s Ice Hockey</option>
    <option value="MLA" >Men&#x27;s Lacrosse</option>
    <option value="MSO" >Men&#x27;s Soccer</option>
    <option value="MTE" >Men&#x27;s Tennis</option>
    <option value="MVB" >Men&#x27;s Volleyball</option>
    <option value="WBB" >Women&#x27;s Basketball</option>
    <option value="WBW" >Women&#x27;s Bowling</option>
    <option value="WFH" >Field Hockey</option>
    <option value="WIH" >Women&#x27;s Ice Hockey</option>
    <option value="WLA" >Women&#x27;s Lacrosse</option>
    <option value="WSB" selected>Softball</option>
    <option value="WSO" >Women&#x27;s Soccer</option>
    <option value="WSV" >Women&#x27;s Beach Volleyball</option>
    <option value="WTE" >Women&#x27;s Tennis</option>
    <option value="WVB" >Women&#x27;s Volleyball</option>
</select>
```

I have been trying to insert "selected" into

```
<option value="WSB" >Softball</option>
```

Using this python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'http://stats.ncaa.org/rankings/ranking_summary'
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
sport = soup.find(value="WSB")
sport.insert(0,"selected")
print(sport)
```

But this produces the result:

```
<option value="WSB">selectedSoftball</option>
```

I really don't know much about HTML so i'm having a hard time finding where to look for a solution, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BeautifulSoup4, attributes are stored similarly to a dictionary. To modify the `selected` attribute of the `<option>`, use `sport['selected'] = ''`.

Comment: ok cool, so just to verify i get this: ('<option selected="" value="WSB">Softball</option>')  is this the same as this: <option value="WSB" selected>Softball</option>   ?

Comment: @zacpdx yes it is